# Why Compare ins System.Single casts float value to double?

Tags: c#

I was peeking class `System.Single`'s CompareTo method with Resharper and found out this is the implementation:

```
public int CompareTo(float value)
{
  if ((double) this < (double) value)
    return -1;
  if ((double) this > (double) value)
    return 1;
  if ((double) this == (double) value)
    return 0;
  if (!float.IsNaN(this))
    return 1;
  return !float.IsNaN(value) ? -1 : 0;
}
```

Why the casts?

I don't know if resharper shows a decompiled version or the exact source code but here is a screenshot.

[image]

You can see other methods do that too.

Edit: At the top of opened document it says it's a decompiled version

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: System.Single
// Assembly: mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// MVID: 2E305EDD-3CCB-4D57-A152-462A7A1E3C46
// Assembly location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll
```

**EDIT 2:** I decompiled using ildasm.exe as JonSkeet suggests and here is the IL code it shows. Seems Resharper is showing the casts absent any IL instruction.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like that in the .NET Core source code: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/shared/System/Single.cs#L144

Comment: You don't have to decompile. There's the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/single.cs,105) (or the Core Framework is in github)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. But either way why are the casts in the decompiled version? Does .Net compiler adds this to IL or is this some glitch with resharper tool?

Comment: I'd suggest using ildasm to have a look at the IL. You can write your own code that looks the same if you want to check what the C# compiler does in various situations (e.g. based on optimization flags).

Comment: Per the CLI spec - "Storage locations for floating-point numbers (statics, array elements, and fields of classes) are of fixed size. The
supported storage sizes are
.
float32 and float64. Everywhere else (on the evaluation stack, as arguments, as
return types, and as local variables) floating-point numbers are represented using an internal floating-point
type" - which means float and double comparisons are indistinguishable from each other (but since the internal representation has to be > double, it's slightly more accurate to depict it as a double comparison)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That makes sense. It looks like Resharper took the liberty to explicitly show this!!

Comment: Decompiling code back to C# is an imperfect art, Resharper fumbles it badly here and there is no cast in the C# nor the CIL.  There are better decompilers out there, Reflector doesn't show a cast,  ILSpy is free.  And keep in mind that you can always get back to real source code with the referencesource.microsoft.com web site, just type "single.compareto" in the search box.